# Assets not uploading files or building indexes.

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

I am working on a site that had assets installed and working.  Then one of the other developers installed freeform and added .htaccess rules that removed the index.php and forced us to add www to the url.

I checked the upload directories in Content > File Upload Preferences and tried to run the index updates and refresh.

I get no loading bar, no spinning button, no thumbnails and the upload file button is inactive.  I checked the upload directory directory permissions and those are correct. I also tested hiding each line and then each group of lines from the .htaccess file to see if that would effect it.  No luck.

I am using EE 2.6.1 and Assets 2.1.3.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using

Comment: According to console, I get the following error:

this._element is undefined

Comment: What file is generating the error? Is it possible to get some CP access?